# existence or non-existence of a limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

We have the dynamical system
$$
\begin{cases}
x' =x(x^2+y^2-2x-3)-y \\
 y' =y(x^2+y^2-2x-3)+x 
\end{cases}
$$

the question is: is there a limit cycle for the above system?
To solve this question, I have transformed it into polar coordinates
I got  $r'=r(r^2-2r\cosθ-3)$
Now, I do not  know how to deal with the term '$\cosθ$'?
Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making $x \dot x + y \dot y$ we have

$$
\frac 12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2) = (x^2+y^2)\left((x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2-r^2\right)
$$

with $x_0 = 1, y_0 = 0, r = 2$

this characterizes an attractive region for $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2<r^2$ and an expansive region for $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2>r^2$ with a limit cycle for $(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$

[image]